# Screen resolution for certain program?

Tags: screen, unity3d

I have a Dell xps 15 9550, it has a 4k screen and im running it with ubuntu 16.10. Every thing works great! The only problem i have is when trying to use the unity game engine, as the editor does not have an option to change screen resolution this makes it barely usable. I cannot read at all as the size of the text and buttons are to small.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, I could write a script that alters screen resolution conditionally when your app is open or in focus. Would that be something you're interested in ?

Comment: that would be great @Serg !

Comment: Alright. I'll write a script and will post tomorrow, potentially on Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you're looking for is called 'xrandr' and you can use it to dynamically resize the screen/resolution depending on how you want to run it. I would wrap my Unity script in some xrandr commands that will resize, launch unity and then restore the resolution upon exit.